# What makes Lattice Yang-Mills hard?

Tags: path-integral, yang-mills, lattice-model

I've been reading up on non-perturbative [Yang-Mills](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yang%E2%80%93Mills_theory), and have found the following equation:
$$Z[\gamma, g^2, G]=\int \! \prod e^{-S}\mathrm{d}U_i$$

Now I don't know much about computational physics, so this question might be extremely naive, but why is it difficult to evaluate that functional integral? Is it simply too computationally taxing for a computer to handle it? Is it exactly solvable by current mean of computational physics?

Comment: Write out what the product the is taken over. Then think about what *kind* of integral this is. Marvelously, exact solutions exist [in two dimensions](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1104248198) (then again, two dimensions are kinda boring - no local d.o.f.).